# Как передать выборку или таблицу в процедуру как параметр?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Никак не разберусь с вопросом. Структура процедуры:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <Имя_процедуры> (
  <переменная_1> IN <тип_переменной_1>,
  ...
) AS
  <внутренняя_переменная_1> <тип_внутренней_переменной_1>;
...
BEGIN
  <Тело на языке PL/SQL>;
END;
/
```

Но что, если я хочу передать в переменную какую-то выборку?

Например, если у меня есть временная таблица, то передать всю таблицу как переменную, из которой в теле процедуры можно было бы делать какие-то выборки.

Comment: Как вариант можно передавать массивы или курсоры.  Не припоминаю способа передавать именно таблицу. Еще можно передать имя таблицы и дальше все делать через динамический sql, Но такие решения не очень удобно поддерживать

Comment: Временными таблицами в оракле называют таблицы, созданные как `create temporary table ...`. Это, по сути, обычная таблица, только все время пустая. Ее саму по себе никуда передать нельзя.

Comment: @lDrakonl В принципе, можно назвать таблицей массив, описанный как `TYPE MY_TABLE IS TABLE OF ...`. Ну а чо? Слово table есть, значит, таблица ;)

Comment: Интересно, для чего это может понадобится. Если есть готовая временная таблица, то не проще ли использовать в процедуре просто конкретную таблицу, не передавая ее на вход. А если готовой таблицы нет - то преобразовывать это что то в таблицу перед передачей на вход нет смысла, надо передавать то, что есть, курсор или табличный тип

Comment: @Mike 
Есть какая-то база данных. Есть какой-то запрос из этой базы вытаскивающий выборку, попутно джойня друг к другу кучу разных таблиц. Результат запроса нигде не хранится. Вот я и подумал перед использованием процедуры выполнить запрос во временную таблицу и как-то передать её в процедуру.

Comment: Проще всего наверное было бы объявить табличный тип подходящей под запрос структуры, заполнить его с помощью BULK COLLECT (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html) и передать этот заполненный тип. А в процедуре тогда запрос будет выглядеть как `select * from Table(входная-переменная-с-коллекцией)`

Comment: Но если данных много и в память может не влезать, то я бы этот запрос обернул бы в функцию, которая возвращала бы его построчно с помощью PIPE ROW и в процедуре уже вызывал эту функцию с целью получать строки из нее в виде `select * from Table(имя-функции() )`.

Comment: Еще можно открыть курсор для чтения выборки и передать его. Но в оracle < 12c напрямую его в запросе использовать нельзя и придется опять же сделать функцию, которая будет читать переданный курсор построчно и возвращать запись через PIPE ROW

Comment: "какая-то база данных","какой-то запрос" -  такого в природе не бывает, есть определённая база с определённой структурой и в ней вы можете выполнить определённый запрос. "джойня друг к другу кучу разных таблиц" - куча это новая единица измерения сложности запроса?  "Результат запроса нигде не хранится" - а куда он девается? Пока курсор не закрыт, он всё таки где-то хранится.  Пока вы чётко не представите, что у вас есть и что должно получиться, вам будет трудно задать конкретный вопрос  на который можно будет дать аргументированный ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
create or replace type itemRow as object (id number,  name varchar2 (32));
/
create or replace type itemRows  is table of itemRow;
/

create or replace function passonItems (resultSet sys_refcursor) return itemRows pipelined is
    item itemRow;
begin 
    <<processResultSet>> loop
        fetch resultSet into item;
        exit processResultSet when resultSet%notfound;
        -- здесь требуемая логика
        pipe row (item);
    end loop processResultSet;
    close resultSet;
    return;
end;
/

select * 
from table (
    passonItems (
        cursor (select itemRow(level, 'item '||level) from dual connect by level<4)
        )
);

        ID NAME                           
---------- --------------------------------
         1 item 1                          
         2 item 2                          
         3 item 3
```

Функция пока ничего не делает, только пропускает 1:1 данные через себя.

Comment: Привет! Сейчас несколько не актуально (в итоге тогда создал таблицу, сделал в неё селект и вызвал без параметров процедуру), но отмечу ответ за неимением других. Однажды попробую, когда вновь возникнет беда или вернусь к той.

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать своё решение как ответ, и даже отметить его как принятый.  Не актуально для вас, но данный ресурс это база знаний и кому-то может ещё будет полезно при поиске решения.

Comment: Да, но по факту я не решил задачу в поставленном виде - нет передачи значения в процедуру, просто "глобальная переменная".

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с версии 18c появились [полиморфные табличные функции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-981102A8-5204-4931-B10A-93486304B184), которые принимают как параметр выборку, всю таблицу или представление.

Простейший пример - ничего не делать (*no operation*), только логировать:

```sql
create or replace package noopPkg as
    function get (t table) return table pipelined row polymorphic using noopPkg;   
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t;
    procedure fetch_rows;
end noopPkg;
/
create or replace package body noopPkg as
    function describe (tab in out dbms_tf.table_t) return dbms_tf.describe_t as
    begin
        for ix in 1..tab.column.count () loop
            tab.column (ix).for_read := true;
        end loop;
        return null;
    end;
    procedure fetch_rows as
        rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t; 
    begin 
        dbms_tf.get_row_set (rowset);
        dbms_tf.trace (rowset);
        /*** здесь реализация логики с набором данных (rowset) ***/
    end;
end noopPkg;
/
```

Тестовые данные:

```sql
create table t1 (id number, memo varchar2 (32)); 
insert into t1
    select rownum id, 'memo '||column_value memo
    from xmlTable ('"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"');
```

Запуск с таблицей как параметр и вывод результата:

```
select * from noopPkg.get (t1);

        ID MEMO                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 memo aaa                        
         2 memo bbb                        
         3 memo ccc                        

.... [1] = {"ID":1, "MEMO":"memo aaa"}
.... [2] = {"ID":2, "MEMO":"memo bbb"}
.... [3] = {"ID":3, "MEMO":"memo ccc"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с 19.06 можно написать [SQL-MACRO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-0A638FCA-89C2-44E0-A5D5-0D09800D920D). Это функция, которая может принять таблицу как параметер. Эффективно будет выполнен запрос, который эта функция возвращает.

Простейший пример - продублировать записи любой таблицы с новым идентификатором:

```
create table t1 (id, name) as
    select 1, 'name1' from dual 
/
create or replace function dup (t dbms_tf.table_t) return varchar2 sql_macro is
begin 
    return q'[
        select t.*, sys_guid () guid from t
        cross join (select * from dual connect by level<=2)]';
end;
/
```

Запрос и результат (на [Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kq32p03bonlg8inp055tj58h0)):

```
select * from dup (t1)
/

ID  NAME    GUID
--  ------  --------------------------------
1   name1   B0CEC720D62E629AE05302A0C40A876D
1   name1   B0CEC720D62F629AE05302A0C40A876D
```

Answer (score -1):

Совсем уже неактуально, но всё же напишу коммент :)
У меня была похожая задача — закинуть таблицы параметром в процедуру, создать таблицу с внешним ключом к первичным ключам таблиц из параметров. Я в итоге просто прописала так:

```
create or replace procedure table_creation (table_a varchar2, table_b varchar2)
```

Поскольку у меня на тесте могли написать названия таблиц и ловеркейсом, то добавила две переменные, которым передавала значения
типа upper(table_a). Ну и в запросах внутри процедуры просто указывала, что название таблицы должно быть равно тому, что в параметре (с учётом кейса — равно значению переменной, которую описала выше). Так сказать, ленивый вариант для ленивых, там выше какие-то интересные способы, я бы до такого сама не дошла.

Comment: Комментарии нужно писать к комментариям.

Comment: Скорее всего, вы не до конца поняли вопрос, его автор вовсе не имел ввиду передать _имя таблицы_ как параметер.

Comment: А, о, прошу прощения тогда, я всё ещё новичок на этом сайте, не до конца разобралась в функционале :)